# Splitting an array of child in columns Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I just started flutter, and i managed to make the 4 buttons for a quiz and in portrait they appear properly in 1 column but when i turn to landscape i want them to be slpit in 2 columns (2 buttons left 2 buttons on the right)

```
  var questions = <Widget>[];
      for (int i = 0; i < quizClass.getOptionsLength(); i++) {
        questions.add(
          Expanded(
            child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
              child: FlatButton(
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18.0),
                  ),
                  textColor: Colors.white,
                  color: Colors.yellow.shade500,
                  onPressed: () {
                    checkAnswer(quizClass.getQuestionOption(i));
                  },
                  child: Text(
                    quizClass.getQuestionOption(i),
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20.0),
                  )),
            ),
          ),
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do that is using an OrientationBuilder

```
OrientationBuilder(
          builder: (context, orientation) {
          return Center(
 
            child: orientation == Orientation.portrait? 
             Column(
              children: <Widget>[
               button1,
               button2,
               button3,
               button4,
            ]): 
            Row(
             children:<Widget>[

             Column(
              children: <Widget>[
               button1,
               button2,
               ]),

             Column(
              children: <Widget>[
               button3,
               button4,
               ])
            ])
            );
           }
          )
```

This will change the displayed widget depending on the current orientation of the screen. Hope it works for you!

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Widget> widgets = questions.map((q) => q).toList();

var column = Column(children: widgets);
var row = Row(children: widgets);

bool isPortrait = MediaQuery.of(context).orientation == Orientation.portrait;

return Scaffold(
   body: isProtrait ? column : row,
);
```